# File Not Found Bridging Header Ionic Cordova

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, bridging-header

I have an Ionic Cordova application with a custom plugin and when running I am getting this error:

```
/Users/brendanwinter/Desktop/ionic/platforms/ios/MyApp/Bridging-Header.h:31:9: error: 'ProjectSDK/ProjectSDK.h' file not found
#import <ProjectSDK/ProjectSDK.h>
        ^
<unknown>:0: error: failed to import bridging header '/Users/brendanwinter/Desktop/ionic/platforms/ios/MyApp/Bridging-Header.h'
```

It seems the error is here:

```
error: 'ProjectSDK/ProjectSDK.h' file not found
    #import <ProjectSDK/ProjectSDK.h>
```

I am using

- `cordova-plugin-swift-support` plugin

**ProjectSDK-Bridging-Header.h** file in plugin folder contains:

```
#import <ProjectSDK/ProjectSDK.h>
```

**plugin.xml** contains

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<plugin id="cordova-projectsdkplugin" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://apache.org/cordova/ns/plugins/1.0" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <name>ProjectSDKPlugin</name>
    <js-module name="ProjectSDKPlugin" src="www/ProjectSDKPlugin.js">
        <clobbers target="projectsdk" />
    </js-module>
    <platform name="ios">
      <config-file target="config.xml" parent="/*">
        <feature name="ProjectSDK">
          <param name="ios-package" value="ProjectSDK" />
        </feature>
      </config-file>
      <framework src="src/ios/ProjectSDK.framework" custom="true" />
      <header-file src="src/ios/ProjectSDK-Bridging-Header.h" />
      <source-file src="src/ios/ProjectSDK.swift" />
    </platform>
</plugin>
```

It runs using Xcode but when running `ionic cordova run ios` it gives the error above.

What directory does the Bridging Header pull from?
I have tried putting the framework at the same level as Bridging-Header, and ProjectSDK-Bridging-Header, but does not work.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you added those tags manually in plugin.xml ?

Comment: @rajpeer Yes, I added those tags manually. It seems to recognize the Bridging-Header but cannot import it because it cannot find the framework. The framework can be found when running in Xcode but cannot be found when using the CLI.

Comment: whenever you install any cordova plugin to ionic, no need of doing any changes in any file. so don't add manually

Comment: @rajpeer This is for a custom plugin though, I'll upload the plugin.xml if it helps.

Comment: i think this link may useful for you https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-add-swift-support

Comment: @rajpeer I have reviewed the link and have followed the example within `cordova-plugin-permissionScope` to import the Bridging-Header with a 'prefixed Bridging-Header file' but it does not seem to import the framework when running from the CLI.